# Should I avoid message inheritance in WCF?

Tags: wcf, inheritance, message, contract

Generally, I try and avoid using inheritance in WCF contracts, preferring composition.

But in the following situation...

- I have a service operation that can result in one of two things: ResultA and ResultB.
- There is a boolean/enum in the response message to report this outcome.
- There are a number of other properties in the response message. Some of these are only relevant in the event of ResultA and some are only relevant in the event of ResultB.

I see my options as being:

1. Have a single response message contract that contains everything and when properties are not relevant, they are left as null. The client then has to look at the bool/enum to see if its ResultA or ResultB and ignore properties accordingly.
2. Have 2 response messages contracts, both inheriting from a shared base. One representing ResultA and its relevant properties and one representing ResultB and its relevant properties.

I much prefer option 2 for a number of reasons, but it breaks the composition over inheritance rule.

What do people think?

Answer (score 2):

My gut feeling here is "redesign your interface". Having methods with dubious return types is generally not a sign of good design. This leads to a lot of unnecessary and error-prone logic in every caller of the method.

So I would suggest "secret option number 3": refactor the interface into two separate methods.

Answer (score 0):

All rules are meant to be broken.  If you are reusing objects and the systems allows you to use inheritance... why not use it?  As [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/11/favor-composition-over-inheritance-and-other-pithy-catch-phrases.aspx) puts it... think for yourself.

Limiting yourself by a set of artificial rules is a great way to make you work much more difficult.  There is a reason we can use inheritance, and I say this is one of them.

[Prefer Composition Over Inheritance (Steve Rowe)](http://blogs.msdn.com/steverowe/archive/2008/04/28/prefer-composition-over-inheritance.aspx)  Here is another angle.  But if you read it he is talking about the reuse of function, not data.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer composition over inheritance != Never use inheritance  :-)